# Why has the author put "which is" here？

Tags: grammar

The sentence is：
**Raw results give a cloud of points where the main tendencies can already be seen, but which is hardly interpretable.**

Should I remove the "which" or the "which is", by which I assume it will be more simple.

Comment: "tendencies" is plural, "is" is singular. You'd need "are". "Which" can stay but removing it would be clearer.

Comment: All right, so you mean the "which" must stay？

Comment: Can stay, if you like. Or can go.

Comment: If it is the cloud of points that is hardly interpretable, then the sentence is correct as it stands. However, whether that is what you meant or you meant that the raw results are hardly interpretable, your best bet is to split the sentence into two sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *which is*, then *which* must refer to *cloud* because *cloud* and *is* are both singular. But *is* feels awkward in the sentence because *is* is closer to the noun *tendencies* than to *cloud*. *Which are* would be easier to read.

However, *which* feels stiff and unnecessarily formal in this sentence. I would suggest this alternative: **Raw results give a cloud of points where the main tendencies can already be seen, but are hardly interpretable.** This eliminates the formal *which*, and both *tendencies* and *are* are plural.

Comment: well, i think so

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is "hardly interpretable". It could either be "a cloud of points" or "the main tendencies". 
If it is "the main tendencies", kevinbatchcom offers a good option to rephrase. If, however, it is "a cloud of points", then the original sentence is correct, but not easy to read. I would suggest to split it in two: 
**Raw results give a cloud of points where the main tendencies can already be seen. However, this representation is hardly interpretable.**